# Nack all messages before current message and Ack current message (rabbitmq, java)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

```
channel.basicQos(1);

while (true) {
    GetResponse res = channel.basicGet(TEST_QUEUE, false);
    if (res != null) {
        deliveryTag = res.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
    }

    // Handle all messages If the condition is true
    if (condition) {
        // nack all messages unhandled previously
        channel.basicNack(deliveryTag - 1, true, true);

        // ack current message only
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
    }
    else {
        // Do not handle current message and continue to get next one
    }           
}
```

Q1. 
I'm not sure If I can use both nack and ack at the same time.
Can I use deliveryTag - 1 to indicate all previous messages?

In short, I want to skip all messages which do not meet the if condition.
If current message meets the condition then nack all skipped messages and ack current one.
By doing this, I want to delay handling some particular messages.

Q2.
I'm afraid If I write as while (true) and there are multiple workers running then channel.basicQos(1) will not work as expected.
Should I write code like this to limit the count? or How should I write to ensure that all other workers can get messages evenly?

```
int prefetch = 1;
int count = 0;
while (count++ <= prefetch) {
}
```

Q3.
I've noticed The worker program will not terminate as long as the connection is open.
How long will the connection be opend and should I need to close it manually?

Finally, 
RabbitMQ java client API vs AmqpTemplate vs RabbitTemplate which one is more suitable in this case(not using the MessageListener(ChannelAwareMessageListener) model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 - it should work ok. Have you tried it and found problems? Yes, the tag is incremented for each delivery.

Q2 - `basicQos` has no bearing on `basicGet()` - it's only used with `basicConsume()`.

Q3 - You need to close the connection when you are complete.

Finally; it depends. If you want Spring's higher level support (message conversion etc), then use it; if you want to deal with the raw data API, don't use Spring.

The `RabbitTemplate` doesn't directly support `basicGet` with user managed acks/nacks, except via its `execute` method with a channel callback.